# Dependent features configured but no package ID was set. Android two apps of one project.... Admin and User

Tags: android, kotlin, android-productflavors, build-variant

[error screen while building superadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AMYF.png)

Hello guys, I wanted to make an android app of admin separate from user app so I decided to make a module for it .SuperAdmin is an application module.I want to make it for only admin and this error is showing while building..... This error is only showing when I am using something from default App module i.e User app .

Is there necessary to make a library between them to communicate with each other?

Comment: Please add the text from the image build output and the .kt file to the question so people can read and copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way to solve this is by using build variants and product flavors . Read about this [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants).  You will doing something like this below in `build.gradle`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {
        debug{...}
        release{...}
    }
    // Specifies one flavor dimension.
    flavorDimensions "type"
    productFlavors {
        user {
            dimension "type"
            applicationIdSuffix ".user" //It will be like com.example.app.user . You can remove this applicationIdSuffix property here. So it will build as com.example.app with no suffix
            versionNameSuffix "-demo"
        }
        admin {
            dimension "type"
            applicationIdSuffix ".admin" //It will be building as com.example.app.admin
            versionNameSuffix "-full"
        }
    }
}
```

In code , you can do conditional logics something like below.

```
if(BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "user"){
//showUserScreen or hide some button
}else{
//showAdminScreen or show some button
}
```

In build variants you will be having `userDebug`, `userRelease` , `adminDebug` and `adminRelease` for two different flavours.